# How do I pass Enumerations as text into VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, string, text, enumeration

I'm creating a Conditional Formatting tool. The user completes a spreadsheet, describing which formats they'd like to add and where.

My VBA labels each column in this spreadsheet with a column index number and passes each element to the VBA as it loops through each row.

I'm having a Type mismatch error with this statement (below), and I've worked out the problem is with passing the enumeration in for the Rule Type and Operator arguments in Format Conditions method; VBA is reading it as text whereas from research I understand enumerations are essentially long types in text form(?).

```
    Sub s_ApplyFormats()

    Dim rng_FormattingInfo As Range
    Dim rng_RowItem As Range

    Const int_VBAFormatTypeCol As Integer = 2  'xlCellValue or xlExpression
    Const int_VBAOperatorCol As Integer = 4 'xlEqual, xlBetween, etc.
    Const int_FormulaCol As Integer = 5
    Const int_WorksheetCol As Integer = 6
    Const int_RangeCol As Integer = 7
    Const int_FormatCol As Integer = 8
    Const int_StopIfTrueCol As Integer = 10
    'The column numbers of the relevant columns in the Conditional Formatting admin worksheet

    Set rng_FormattingInfo = Range("rng_ConditionalFormattingData")
    'Contains all columns in the Conditional Formatting admin worksheet          

    For Each rng_RowItem In rng_FormattingInfo.Rows
        With Worksheets(rng_RowItem.Cells(int_WorksheetCol).Value2) _
         .Range(rng_RowItem.Cells(int_RangeCol)).FormatConditions _
          .Add(rng_RowItem.Cells(int_VBAFormatTypeCol).Value2, rng_RowItem.Cells(int_VBAOperatorCol).Value2, _
           rng_RowItem.Cells(int_FormulaCol))
            .Font.ColorIndex = rng_RowItem.Cells(int_FormatCol).Font.ColorIndex
            .Interior.ColorIndex = rng_RowItem.Cells(int_FormatCol).Interior.ColorIndex
        End With
    Next rng_RowItem

    End Sub
```

As a potential solution I could create a lookup in the workbook, so that when a user picks "xlCellValue" in the spreadsheet, the enumerated value (1) is passed to the VBA instead. This requires me to make an list of the string and numerical forms of each enumeration.

However, is there a way I can pass the string form of an enumeration into VBA from a cell?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your sheet?

Comment: To answer your explicit question: No, VBA can't use a string for an enumeration. It requires some kind of "look-up", either in the code or, as you mention, in a Worksheet or other source.

Comment: @CindyMeister - That answers my question, thank you.

Comment: As a side note, do not use `Integer`, rather prefer to use `Long` in VBA. The reason is that `Integer` is 16bit and `Long` is 32 bit. You can safely replace every instance of Integer with Long, unless the API explicitly needs an `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

You could explicity cast the long value from the cell to its corresponding Excel `Enum` using a couple of custom functions.

```
Sub s_ApplyFormats()

    Dim rng_FormattingInfo As Range
    Dim rng_RowItem As Range
    Dim i As Long 'used in loop for row numbers
    Dim VBAFormatTypeCol As Excel.XlFormatConditionType, VBAOperatorCol As Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator

    Set rng_FormattingInfo = Range("rng_ConditionalFormattingData")       

    For Each rng_RowItem In rng_FormattingInfo.Rows
        i = i + 1
        With Worksheets(rng_RowItem.Cells(i, int_WorksheetCol).Value2)

            VBAFormatTypeCol = FormatTypeToXLEnum(CLng(Trim(rng_RowItem.Cells(i, int_VBAFormatTypeCol).Value2)))
            VBAOperatorCol = OperatorTypeToXLEnum(CLng(Trim(rng_RowItem.Cells(i, int_VBAOperatorCol).Value2)))

            With .Range(rng_RowItem.Cells(i, int_RangeCol))
                    .FormatConditions.Add(VBAFormatTypeCol, VBAOperatorCol, rng_RowItem.Cells(i, int_FormulaCol))
            End With 

            .Font.ColorIndex = rng_RowItem.Cells(i, int_FormatCol).Font.ColorIndex
            .Interior.ColorIndex = rng_RowItem.Cells(i, int_FormatCol).Interior.ColorIndex

        End With

        VBAFormatTypeCol = Empty
        VBAOperatorCol = Empty

    Next rng_RowItem

End Sub


Private Function FormatTypeToXLEnum(ByVal FormatType as Long) As Excel.XlFormatConditionType

    Select Case FormatType

        Case 1
            FormatTypeToXLEnum = xlCellValue

        Case 2
            FormatTypeToXLEnum = xlExpression 

    End Select

End Function 


Private Function OperatorTypeToXLEnum(ByVal OperatorType as Long) As Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator

    Select Case OperatorType

        Case 1
            OperatorTypeToXLEnum = xlBetween 

        Case 2
            OperatorTypeToXLEnum = xlNotBetween  

        Case 3
            OperatorTypeToXLEnum = xlEqual  

        Case 4
            OperatorTypeToXLEnum = xlNotEqual  

        Case 5
            OperatorTypeToXLEnum = xlGreater 

        Case 6
            OperatorTypeToXLEnum = xlLess  

        Case 7
            OperatorTypeToXLEnum = xlGreaterEqual  

        Case 8
            OperatorTypeToXLEnum = xlLessEqual   

    End Select

End Function
```

**Original:**

Try explicitly converting the cell values to a long type. Consider the following:

```
'Define constants at the top of the module
Private Const int_VBAFormatTypeCol As Long = 2  'xlCellValue or xlExpression
Private Const int_VBAOperatorCol As Long = 4 'xlEqual, xlBetween, etc.
Private Const int_FormulaCol As Long = 5
Private Const int_WorksheetCol As Long = 6
Private Const int_RangeCol As Long = 7
Private Const int_FormatCol As Long = 8
Private Const int_StopIfTrueCol As Long = 10

Sub s_ApplyFormats()

    Dim rng_FormattingInfo As Range
    Dim rng_RowItem As Range
    Dim i As Long 'used in loop for row numbers
    Dim VBAFormatTypeCol As Long, VBAOperatorCol As Long

    Set rng_FormattingInfo = Range("rng_ConditionalFormattingData")       

    For Each rng_RowItem In rng_FormattingInfo.Rows
        i = i + 1
        With Worksheets(rng_RowItem.Cells(i, int_WorksheetCol).Value2)

            VBAFormatTypeCol = CLng(Trim(rng_RowItem.Cells(i, int_VBAFormatTypeCol).Value2))
            VBAOperatorCol = CLng(Trim(rng_RowItem.Cells(i, int_VBAOperatorCol).Value2))

            With .Range(rng_RowItem.Cells(i, int_RangeCol))
                    .FormatConditions.Add(VBAFormatTypeCol, VBAOperatorCol, rng_RowItem.Cells(i, int_FormulaCol))
            End With 

            .Font.ColorIndex = rng_RowItem.Cells(i, int_FormatCol).Font.ColorIndex
            .Interior.ColorIndex = rng_RowItem.Cells(i, int_FormatCol).Interior.ColorIndex

        End With

        VBAFormatTypeCol = Empty
        VBAOperatorCol = Empty

    Next rng_RowItem

End Sub
```

Try running it and see what you get.

Comment: It doesn't like the CLng lines unfortunately; type mismatch still

Comment: @jakrooster You're welcome! Let me know if it works.